# Create function to extract data from dataframe based on value

Tags: python, function, dataframe, data-extraction

I have a dataframe containing e-sports game data:

```
index   result   map_index   map_games_total   map_win_rate   
0       win      1           3                 0.66           
1       win      3           2                 0.5            
2       loss     3           2                 0.5            
3       loss     2           1                 0.0           
4       win      1           3                 0.66           
5       loss     1           3                 0.66          
6       win      4           1                 1.0
```

I would like to define a function that automatically identifies the three most played maps (map = map_index) and creates a new dataframe containing only the rows for those maps for each of the identified maps. So for the example above that would be something like this:

subdf_1

```
index   result   map_index   map_games_total   map_win_rate   
    0       win      1           3                 0.66           
    4       win      1           3                 0.66           
    5       loss     1           3                 0.66
```

subdf_2

```
 index   result   map_index   map_games_total   map_win_rate   
    1       win      3           2                 0.5            
    2       loss     3           2                 0.5
```

subdf_3

```
 index   result   map_index   map_games_total   map_win_rate   
    3       loss     2           1                 0.0
```

subdf_4

```
 index   result   map_index   map_games_total   map_win_rate   
    6       win      4           1                 1.0
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. (a) what is 'most played'? (b) You mention three most played, but have four sub-dataframes in the results.

Comment: By most played I refer to the values in column 'map_games_total' (sum of the occurence of that map in the df). And there are four sub dataframes in my example because there are two maps that are 'third most played'. I hope that clarifies how I mean it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
results = {}

for i, j in enumerate(df.map_win_rate.unique()):
    results[f'subdf_{i}'] = df[df.map_win_rate.eq(j)]
```

---

```
print(results['subdf_1'])

   index result  map_index  map_games_total  map_win_rate
1      1    win          3                2           0.5
2      2   loss          3                2           0.5

print(results['subdf_2'])

   index result  map_index  map_games_total  map_win_rate
3      3   loss          2                1           0.0

...
```

Comment: Your way is better than my post, but I think you need to change map_win_rate by map_inex, moreover like my answer just before your results isn't store by map_games_total.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
def subdf(df,column):
    list_sub_df=[]
    for value in df.column.unique():
        list_sub_df.append(df[df[column]==value])
    return(list_sub_df)
```

maybe you had to do a sort by value before